# LESS CSS selector combining not and :after pseudo element

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I have 3 main elements: `.submit-it`, `.send-it`, `.get-results`.

I want all of their `:after` elements to have certain styling EXCEPT if they have the classes `excluded`, or `error`. I thought this would work, but it doesn't.

```
.submit-it, .send-it, .get-results {
  &:not(.excluded), &:not(.error) {
    &:after {
      content: 'text';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By generating the following selectors, you are essentially styling all `:after` pseudo elements regardless of their classes.

```
.submit-it:not(.excluded):after,
.submit-it:not(.error):after, { ... }
```

By selecting all elements without class `excluded`, and all elements without class `error`, you are indirectly selecting ***all*** the elements since these two events are not mutually exclusive.

Therefore you would chain the `:not()` pseudo classes, and replace:

```
&:not(.excluded), &:not(.error)
```

with:

```
&:not(.excluded):not(.error)
```

```
.submit-it, .send-it, .get-results {
  &:not(.excluded):not(.error) {
    &:after {
      content: 'text';
    }
  }
}
```

Which will output:

```
.submit-it:not(.excluded):not(.error):after,
.send-it:not(.excluded):not(.error):after,
.get-results:not(.excluded):not(.error):after {
  content: 'text';
}
```